# OpenGL driver implementation

Tags: opengl, implementation

How is OpenGl driver implemented?
i'm trying to understand how it is possible to draw geometric primitives on screen?
On the lowest possible level, how can opengl driver draw on screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL drivers don't really draw in the screen, they just command the graphics chip on your graphics card (GPU) to draw into a memory buffer, which is later copied into the screen.

The command protocol for each graphics chip is completely different and manufacturer dependant (usually not public also), graphics APIs such as OpenGL abstract the programmer away from such details.

So, you don't want to get to the lowest possible level, because that means you will be programming registers at the HW level, without any specifications, basically blind.

Comment: what memory buffer? where is it located?

Comment: @DrStrangeLove Usually it's the graphics card memory (VRAM), or in integrated GPUs, just RAM.